# Ember model host adapter not overiding mirage

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I'm using Ember-cli-mirage to mock data. I want to slowly integrate parts of the production api which is located on my local machine at http://localhost:8000. [Ember docs tell me](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_host-customization) that I should be able to set an adapter so I can have a different host for each model.

I have a `customer` model, and have setup ember-cli-mirage which is successfully serving data. The customer model is the first model I want to split out to localhost:8000.

I've setup adapters/customer.js with the following:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend( {
  host: 'http://localhost:8000',
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});
```

But when I make the call I'm getting an error:

```
Mirage: Error: Your Ember app tried to GET 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/customers',
         but there was no route defined to handle this request.
         Define a route that matches this path in your
         mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace?
```

And my header inspector shows that customers is making the request to the mirage server:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:6543/customers
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:[::1]:6543
```

I suspect it's something to do with my config/environment.js setup so I'm looking at a variation of https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/issues/497#issuecomment-183458721 as a potential workaround. But I can't see why mirage won't accept the adapter overide.

Answer (score 0):

Should have read back through the mirage docs for this one. There's a [passthrough function](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/configuration/#passthrough) that allows mirage to pass certain requests through to Ember bypassing mirage:

```
// mirage/config.js
import Mirage from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default function() {

  this.urlPrefix = 'http://localhost:8000';
  this.namespace = '/api/v1';

  // Requests for customers
  this.get('/customers');
  this.get('/customers/:id');
  this.post('/customers');
  this.del('/customers/:id');
  this.patch('/customers/:id');

  // Passthrough to Django API
  this.passthrough('/customers');

}
```

To make this work in my application adapter I added:

```
// app/adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:8000',
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});
```

If this helps you in any way feel free to give this answer an upvote :)